# Creating a subcomponent for each activity - good practice?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I just started learning Dagger and I want to incorporate it into my application, after reading a lot of articles I started using Dagger the following way:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun addMainActivitySubComponent() : MainActivitySubComponent
}

@Module
class ApplicationModule {
    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    fun provideBigClass() = BigClass()
}
```

And for each activity:

```
@ActivityScope                                         
@Subcomponent(modules = [SomeModule::class])      
interface MainActivitySubComponent {                   
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)                 
    fun inject(activity: HomeFragment)                 
}
```

Is creating a subcomponent for each activity good practice or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring separate component for each Activity is not a good idea at all.  The reasoning behind this is very simple - you don't really need all these module/components (as you have already seen by yourself).

However, having just one component that is tied to `Application`'s life-cycle and using it for injection into all `Activities` is also not the optimal solution (this is your friend's approach). It is not optimal because:

1. It restricts you to just one scope (`@Singleton` or a custom one)
2. The only scope you're restricted to makes the injected objects "application singletons", therefore mistakes in scoping or incorrect usage of scoped objects can easily cause global memory leaks
3. You'll want to use Dagger2 in order to inject into `Services` too, but `Services` can require different objects than `Activities` (e.g. `Services` don't need presenters, don't have `FragmentManager`, etc.). By using a single component you loose the flexibility of defining different object graphs for different components.

So, a component per `Activity` is an overkill, but single component for the entire application is not flexible enough. The optimal solution is in between these extremes (as it usually is).

I use the following approach:

1. Single "application" component that provides "global" objects (e.g. objects that hold global state which is shared between all components in the application). Instantiated in `Application`.
2. "Controller" subcomponent of "application" component that provides objects which are required by all user-facing "controllers" (in my architecture these are `Activities` and `Fragments`). Instantiated in each `Activity` and `Fragment`.
3. "Service" subcomponent of "application" component that provides objects which are required by all `Services`. Instantiated in each `Service`.